# jQuery accordion - how to replace the active link with an image instead?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

Does someone know how to replace the active link (which is an image in my code) with another image when you click on it?

http://jsfiddle.net/8bwre/1/

I basically want the image of the 'yellow toilet paper' to be replaced with the 'yellow envelope' when you click on the yellow toilet paper's icon. And same with the other image!

Is there such a solution??

```
    (function($) {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > .day').hide();

    $('.accordion > .click > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();

        if($(this).parent().next().is(':hidden'))
        {
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }

        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">

  <div class="click">
    <a href=""><img src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/images/icons/svg/toilet-paper.svg"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="day">
    <img src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/images/icons/svg/mail.svg">
    <p>Tomatillo sweet pepper carrot salad cress arugula. Kombu cabbage sorrel celery soko plantain tigernut caulie parsnip tomatillo spinach avocado. Spring onion water chestnut parsnip water spinach cress napa cabbage fennel beetroot.</p>
  </div>


  <div class="click">
    <a href=""><img src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/images/icons/svg/retina.svg"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="day">
      <img src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/images/icons/svg/clocks.svg"><p>Kohlrabi sea lettuce wattle seed mung bean asparagus cucumber chard salsify kombu beetroot radicchio black-eyed pea. Scallion salsify beetroot tigernut prairie turnip artichoke daikon celery turnip greens. Horseradish aubergine carrot gumbo maize collard greens potato caulie lentil arugula salsify rock melon fava bean celery.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying the following code you can achieve what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/8bwre/2/

```
(function($) {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > .day').hide();

    $('.accordion > .click > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();

        /******************/
        var currentSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');

        var newSrc = $(this).parent().next().children('img').attr('src');

        $(this).children('img').attr('src', newSrc);

        $(this).parent().next().children('img').attr('src', currentSrc);
        /******************/


        if($(this).parent().next().is(':hidden'))
        {
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }

        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Then in CSS you can hide the second image using `display: none;`

Comment: however, I’ve just noticed there’s an issue with this:

1. click on ‘toiletpaper’ it brings up the ‘envelope’ while the ‘toiletpaper’ is hidden by CSS.
2. now i click on the green ‘tick’ which brings up the ‘clock’
3. and while i did these two steps suddenly ‘toiletpaper’ was replaced by ‘envelope’ :(

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible ;)

One possible solution (it's up to you to code it):

1. Have in your div.click two images, one with a class="closed" the other with a class="open"
2. Use a css to default hide the img.open
3. When opening a part use JS to hide the img.closed and show the img.open

Answer (score 0):

You'd either have to hide the toilet paper or replace it's source attribute:

```
 if($(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    }
```

OR put both images in the same

```
<a href="">
    <img src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/images/icons/svg/toilet-paper.svg">
    <img src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/images/icons/svg/mail.svg" style="display: none;">
 </a>
```

and call on the toggle() function as seen bellow

```
$('.accordion > .click > a').click(function() {
    $(this).children('img').toggle();
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```